# Trying resize an image from drawable?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm trying resize an image contained in my drawable. To do it I created a class that receive String with path image. If the image is in the storage its works fine but if the image contained in drawable doesn't works and throws an exception: `Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException`. The path image is: `android.resource://br.com.williarts.kontrole/2130837614`

How could I do it ?

**ImageView**

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPerfil"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
```

**Activity**

```
ivPerfil = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPerfil);
//image
        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + ivPerfil.getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.icon_usuario) + "/" + R.drawable.icon_usuario);
        fotoPerfil = path.toString();
        ivPerfil.setImageURI(path);
```

**Resize Image**

```
public class ResizeFileImage {
    private File file, novaImagem;
    private Integer width, height;

    public ResizeFileImage(String pathFile, Integer w, Integer h){
        Log.i("PATH FILE->", pathFile);
        file = new File(pathFile);
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }

    public File getResizeFile(){
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;

        try{            
            if(file.getPath().contains("resource")){
                //from drawable
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getCanonicalPath());
            }else{
                //from storage
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.i("ORIGINAL WIDTH->", myBitmap.getWidth() + "");
        Log.i("ORIGINAL HEIGHT->", myBitmap.getHeight() + "");

        Bitmap bmp = getResizedBitmap(myBitmap, height, width);
        Log.i("CHANGE WIDTH->", bmp.getWidth() + "");
        Log.i("CHANGE HEIGHT->", bmp.getHeight() + "");

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        String nomeImg = "teste.png";
        String seuDiretorio = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyApp";

        try{
            File diretorio = new File(seuDiretorio);
            if(!diretorio.exists()){
                diretorio.mkdir();
            }
            File imgToSdcard = new File(seuDiretorio + File.separator + nomeImg);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imgToSdcard, false);
            outputStream.write(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata.length);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("FileOutputStream Exception Error->", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        novaImagem = new File(seuDiretorio + File.separator + nomeImg);
        return novaImagem;
    }

    /** redimensiona o tamanho da imagem */
    private Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }


    public void removeNovaImagem(){
        if(novaImagem != null && novaImagem.exists()){
            novaImagem.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
02-13 17:42:35.967  27424-27424/br.com.williarts.kontrole E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.resource:/br.com.williarts.kontrole/2130837614: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get a path to a resource file since they are inside your application (.apk file). You can copy the resource file to the internal memory if you wish to perform operations on it thanks to the path of the file. An other solution is to load the resource in the memory. You can get a bitmap with :

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
```

or a Drawable with:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon );
```